# How does the sonic screwdriver eliminate the Cybermen in The Age of Steel

Tags: doctor-who, cybermen

The sonic screwdriver is known to do many things (well, as long as it's not to wood). But at the beginning of The Age Of Steel, the Doctor destroys a good few Cybermen by blasting something out of the screwdriver. Any idea how to justify that? Any other examples of the screwdriver having a bit more power than expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the Sonic Screwdriver. A minute later in the episode, Rickey asks what that thing was. That thing being **... nothing. It's tiny. One of those insignificant little power cells that no one ever bothers about, and it's clinging onto life, with one little ounce of reality tucked away inside.**

It's a Tardis Power Cell that the Doctor and Mickey find half way through the 1st part of the Two-Part Cyberman series, *Rise of the Cybermen*. After the Doctor finds it, he charges it with some of his life force (**I just gave away ten years of my life. Worth every second.**).

Comment: Oh I didn't get that he used the power cell. But wouldn't that use up some of the energy that they were patiently waiting for?

Comment: @EtiennePellegrini it's a power cell, it can be charged, then discharge, then charge itself again. Only needed 4 hours the second time around.

Comment: @cde Just hope there's no memory effect. :)